# Synchronizing data between two different databases

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, synchronization

I need to synchronize data between two databases. The primary database is a SQL server database where all insert, update and delete operations take place. The other database is a MySQL database that reflects the state of primary database at the time of synchronization.

Note that Real-time synchronization is not important, the synchronization will done randomly depending on operator and network availability.

My questions:

- What are the possible ways to determine that the two databases are already in sync and synchronization is NOT required
- What are the possible ways to push data from SQL to MySQL server (no need to pull data from MySQL)
- Should I use custom scripting or is there a tool that can take care of the preocess

Answer (score 1):

Try Pentaho Kettle, which is an industrial strength ETL tool. We wrote a custom Perl script to synchronize, which also works, before finding Kettle.