# Database Synchronization for remote development

Tags: database, git, mysql, data-synchronization

As the title describes, I am looking for an efficient way to synchronize the structure & the data of a project's Database.

As I have not found a "right way" to achieve it, I have propose a solution of dumping the Database into a SQL file before every git commit and import the SQL file on each git pull. This results a smart way to administrate data with git, yet this solution doesn't scale and sometimes creates more issues than solutions. For example, it's not an autonomous way so human mistakes are taking place too often, and all the development team should use the same dumping tool.

Any suggestion of your custom solution would be also fine. Thank you!

Cheers!

Comment: This would be helpful. Similar question is asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984517/synchronizing-data-between-two-different-databases

Answer (score 1):

You can compare and synchronize or just view differences between two databases with a help of [Schema/Data Comparison tools](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-synchronization.html) in dbForge Studio for MySQL.

Comment: Nice software indeed! but I have team members working on Linux & MacOS, Does it have a version for those OS as well?

Comment: [dbForge Studio for MySql on Linux family operating systems](http://www.devart.com/blogs/dbforge/index.php/dbforge-studio-mysql-on-linux-operating-systems.html).