# How to Synchronize mysql databases between local and hosted servers automatically?

Tags: php, mysql, high-availability

I would like to synchronize local Mysql db with remote Mysql db.

Due to internet fail, we have to use local application. Once internet problem solved, db should synchronize with remote db.

Because we are using same application in local and remote.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661501/synchronize-mysql-remote-local-database-using-phpmyadmin

Comment: You might want to look up `Replication` in the MySQL Manual

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583/best-tool-for-synchronizing-mysql-databases

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQLyog which has Database synchronization feature to sync two databases if you are looking for open source tool then refer `pt-table-sync` http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-table-sync.html

Answer (score 0):

You can make the dump of your local database, and import that on the hosted server when ready.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would create a table **changes** on a local database and whenever I do any change on the database, it is also saved in the changes table.

For synching then, I'd

- loop through changes table and make query-like string
- copy it to a clipboard
- Have a page on a hosted web with input where to paste that string
- When submitted, PHP explodes the string into different queries
- Loop through queries and perform them against a hosted database

Of course, here intensive validation should be considered to ensure that the pasted text is a query string copied from the local server

Answer (score -2):

I am afraid you need to do the export and import thing. Don't think there is any automatic kind out there..erm, i would like to know as well