# Sync Local Database data to a remote Database

Tags: mysql, synchronization

I'm having a system which runs online. I have to make that system run in localhost. But the original online system should be updated once a day. Anyone know about a tool which can transfer the local database data to the remote database which is MySQL

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984517/synchronizing-data-between-two-different-databases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `mysqldump` that is a native `mysql` tool to create a dump from your database and restore it on the other side ! (but this depends on your database size)
Or you can use `replication` with a `delay` window! 
[For how to replicate your MySQL database follow this article here](http://www.aodba.com/setup-mysql-replication/) !

Comment: Wouldnt mysqldump erase all remote data?

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you have few possibilities.

See [ETL tools](http://www.etltools.net/etl-tools-comparison.html) = launched when you wan't

or [MySQL Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) = a real time sync

or using a tool like [MySQL Administrator](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html), you will be able to schedule a backup and a restore when you wan't

or using file transfer Like FTP (I used it after a server crash. But you need to have same ENV this case)

And you also can develop your own tool (like an ETL tool) to perform this.

Answer (score -3):

I'm pretty sure using cron you are able to do this:

```
crontab -e
```

and inside:

```
0 0 * * * scp /local/database root@foo2.com:/remote/database
```

You would need to set up SSH Keys in order to do this.